# Postgres list all roles with permission to execute a function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-15

I would like to list my functions & stored procedures along with the roles that are able to execute them. I can get similar information on tables via

```
SELECT grantee
    , CONCAT(table_schema, '.', table_name) schema_table
    , CASE WHEN COUNT(privilege_type) = 7 THEN 'ALL' ELSE ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(privilege_type), ', ') END granted_privileges
FROM information_schema.role_table_grants
GROUP BY table_name, table_schema, grantee
ORDER BY grantee, table_schema, table_name;
```

I would like the equivalent of this for functions & stored procedures. I am using Postgres v15.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to query the system catalog `pg_proc` directly:

```
SELECT p.oid::regprocedure AS function_or_procedure,
       a.privilege_type,
       CASE WHEN a.grantee = 0 THEN 'PUBLIC'::text
            ELSE a.grantee::regrole::text
       END AS grantee,
       a.is_grantable
FROM pg_proc AS p
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL aclexplode(
                         coalesce(
                            p.proacl,
                            '{=X/postgres}'::aclitem[]
                         )
                      ) AS a;
```

The query is taking into account that the default privileges are "execute for everybody".